# silverlight oob without window

Tags: silverlight

Can i do a silverlight app without window??

I need somthing like a top bar (Always On Top) of windows remote desktop.

Any Chances???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silverlight 4, within a trusted out of browser application, supports showing a window as always on top, and customizing the window's chrome (with some limitations).

```
void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (App.Current.HasElevatedPermissions && && Application.Current.IsRunningOutOfBrowser)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            App.Current.Host.Content.TopMost = true;
        });
    }
}
```

In the out of browser settings (Project Properties/Silverlight/Out of Browser Settings...), select the option that you want, maybe Borderless Round Corners for example.